# WebRTC : Screenshare video quality constraints not working on latest version of MAC Safari in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, macos, safari, webrtc

I have been trying to set screen share video quality using height constraint but on the latest version of MAC Safari, it's not working.

MAC OS Version: 13.1
Safari Version: 16.2

Here is code

```
let constraints = {
      aspectRatio: 1.777,
      frameRate: 15,
      height: 480
    }

navigator.mediaDevices
.getDisplayMedia({video :constraints})
.then((stream) => {
    // success
})
.catch(e => {
    // error
});
```

I have tried this constraint but not working

```
var constraints = {
      mandatory: {
        maxHeight: 480,
        aspectRatio: 1.777,
        frameRate: 15,
      },
      optional: []
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `16.2.1` and apparently they have improved screen capture in `16.1` to support sharing `Window` or `Screen` when calling `getDisplayMedia` and somehow it breaks `height` and `width` constraints, all you need to do is removed `height` in your constraints then it should works.

```
let constraints = {
      aspectRatio: 1.777,
      frameRate: 15
    }
```

https://webkit.org/blog/13399/webkit-features-in-safari-16-1/

Comment: Just an update, it still not working on `16.1` unfortunately but fine on `16.2.x` and `15.x`

Comment: @Brain nope - still a problem on 16.2 (18614.3.7.1.5)

Answer (score 2):

After checking the webkit update, found the issue has come up due to a change in the WebKit engine.
Here is the [link](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=247310)

The issue will fix in Safari 16.4 version.
Here is the release node [link](https://webkit.org/blog/13639/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-160/)

Answer (score 1):

## 2023/01/10 Update

After hours of investigation for nothing but just people asking for helps and opened WebKit bug tickets without answers. I found Google Meet screen sharing works nicely on all Safari 16.x, so I hijacked the native API `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` to see what are the constraints Google Meet is using and this works nicely for me on `16.1` `16.2`, `16.4` (Safari Technology Preview), `15,x` and `14.x`

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ height: { max: 1205 }, width: { max: 2880 }, frameRate: 5 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm: for us

```
video: { frameRate: '15', width: 1920, height: 1080 }
```

does not work in 16.3 but works in 16.4 (Safari Tech Preview), while

```
video: { frameRate: '15', width: { max: 1920 }, height: { max: 1080 } }
```

works in both 16.3 and 16.4